# Regular Expressions || How to get a "wildcard" in, specifically replace() function

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the following problem, in my replace code I need to found a hole thing, lets say :Hello: and the idea is to find all the word, the full word, and change only the ";" but I am not searching a replacement for :, for all of it, like a wildcard, like a * in CSS, for now I have this

```
var p = document.querySelector("#div1").innerText
document.write(p.replace(/(hi\[\'*)/g, 'hi(\''));
```

My idea is to find something than is like `/(hi\[\'*\'\])/g`

But this exactly wont work

So the result would change from

```js
hi['world']
```

to

```js
hithere('world')
```

Comment: Can the OP please provide 2 two 3 examples that straightforwardly show each input string (or source string) and its expected replacement/result. From the explanation one does not really get the full picture.

Comment: Neo, do you need to replace `hi['blah']` with `hi('blah')`? `p.replace(/(hi\[').*?('])/g, '$1$2')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
console.log("some hi['1 2 3!']".replace(/\bhi\[('.*?')]/g, 'hithere($1)'))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WuQtlQ/2/).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary (the current location must be preceded with a space, punctuation (other than `_`) or start of string
- `hi\[` - `hi[` text
- `('.*?')` - Capturing group 1: a `'`, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and then a `'`
- `]` - a `]` char.